# alguien sabe si será posible que tenga un error de sintaxis?

Tags: java, sql

```
String consulta= "SELECT * FROM Produccion.Transferido WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaEntrega = '"+LineActual+"' AND PendienteEnviar = (SELECT MIN(PendienteEnviar) from Produccion.Transferido) AND Estado = Pendiente";
```

por mas que busco en la sintaxis, no logro encontrar cual es mi error, pareciera estar bien formulada la sentencia de consulta pero no es así, la consulta funciona pero al agregar la ultima parte ..."AND Estado = Pendiente";... la consulta ya no devuelve el valor correcto.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, ¿Cual es el error que te muestra?. No olvides revisar [ask] para que mejores tus preguntas y obtengas excelentes respuestas.

Comment: en realidad no muestra ningun error, sino que ejecuta la consulta per no devuelve el valor correcto a pesar de que las variables a las que se busca obtener estan bien declaradas

Comment: sin la ultima parte de la consulta la sentencia Sí se ejecuta, pero al agregar el "AND Estado = Pendiente" ya la consulta no devuelve los valores que debería

Comment: Revisa sin "AND Estado = Pendiente", si los registros que obtiene no tienen el estado "Pendiente", seguramente es eso

Comment: `Pendiente`, si es una cadena, debiera ir entre comillas simples: `'Pendiente'`.

Comment: La condicion de "AND Estado = Pendiente" si necesito que se cumplan en la consulta, todo los valores que busca esta consulta están en la misma tabla, no entiendo porque con solo agregar esa ultima parte ya no devuelve lo correcto

Comment: ok, intentaré con las comillas simples para verificar que pudiera ser eso!!

Answer (score 2):

Si que tienes un error de sintaxis a la hora de utilizar el String `Pendiente` ya que no le pones comillas simples (en SQL los Strings se especifican con comillas simples)

```
String consulta= "SELECT * FROM Produccion.Transferido WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' AND AreaEntrega = '"+LineActual+"' AND PendienteEnviar = (SELECT MIN(PendienteEnviar) from Produccion.Transferido) AND Estado = 'Pendiente'";
```

Comment: cierto, pero ya intenté tambien poniendole las comillas y aun así no me funciona

Comment: ¿Fíjate en los nombres de tus tablas/columnas, tienes las mayúsculas que quieres especificar?

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error, agradezco mucho la ayuda de todos, el error no estaba en la sintaxis, sino en la forma que la base de datos estaba reconociendo los datos que tenia almacenados, aunque la sentencia estaba bien, no encontraba los datos debido a ese detalle.

Mil gracias a todos los que colaboraron, Pura vida.